# When traveling to Australia and New Zealand in the winter, what to pack?

Tags: australia

I am traveling to Australia and New Zealand in June, but am unsure of what kind of wardrobe to pack!

Comment: a better question would be about the temperatures and conditions to expect, from which you can make your wardrobe choices. Also, Australia is HUGE and what you need will vary with location.

Comment: Are you planning on visiting Darwin, or Kosciusko?

Answer (score 2):

How sensitive to cold are you ? How fashionably conscious are you ?

I suggest bringing at least one good rainwear and one good sweater and some good water resistant walking shoes (or boots)

A quick search says that Auckland NZ temperature vary from 10C-20C (1) and a little bit warmer in Sidney (Aus), but that can vary a lot if going to different areas of both New Zealand or Australia (Darwin, for example is hot).

(1) 
http://www.accuweather.com/en/nz/auckland/252066/june-weather/252066